# Hydration issue in mobile view in nextjs 14

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, hydration, device-detection

Getting hydration issue in mobile responsive view once I refresh the page, it works fine on desktop view but as soon as I check in mobile view and refresh it this appears. I'm using Nextjs 14.1.0(SSG) Listing the console errors below:

1. `Warning: Prop "href" did not match. Server: "http://localhost:3000" Client: "http://localhost:3000/"`
2. `Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <div>.`
3. `Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.`
4. `Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.`

Tried checking the `<p>,<button>` nested in other `<p>` tags,etc but no such thing. Build is working fine & desktop view too but as soon as I switch to mobile mode and refresh, this issue pops up. Suspecting it might be related to react-device-detect

Comment: Still incomplete information Hydration is not only <button /> inside <p /> Element, But it is one of the issue which occurs Hydration error, Here is how to debug easily 1. Undo your changes in the file you think where Hydration error wasn't occur.

Comment: Recently migrated from 12 to 14 and this issue is appearing on mobile view only desktop looks good. Common solutions I tried checking from internet was nesting and package issues like swiper, etc.

Comment: As I am seeing it would need lot's of debugging can provide a straight solution. Best of Luck.